# What does "variable = variable || {}" mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What does this initialization of a variable stand for:

```
var variable = variable  ||  {} ;
```

How and when should it be used?

Comment: See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11.

Comment: Thanks for including that link.  It's nice to actually read this sentence, which has tripped me up in the past: "_The value produced by a && or || operator is not necessarily of type Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand expressions._"

Comment: if this is in the top of a code module, it's for declaring a "namespace" object.  See above mentioned question.

Comment: @skuntsel why did you add the `var`?  It has the potential to completely change the semantics of the question.

Comment: @Alnitak I did that to stress out the initialization during declaration, and because I thought it was more appropriate to be used like that. Doesn't such an assignment (the one without `var`) produce an error if variable isn't declared?

Answer (score 17):

That line of code does the following:

**IF** `variable` is not defined (or has a falsey value) **THEN** set it to an empty object.

**ELSE** do nothing (technically speaking, `variable` gets assigned to itself)

In other words `variable` will be converted to an empty object if it is any of the following:

- false
- undefined
- null
- zero
- NaN
- an empty string

See [toBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) for the spec's definition of *falsey* values.

Comment: "Don't do anything" in terms of outcome, but internally it is an instruction that assigns the variable to itself (may be optimized by the compiler but is still an assignment expression), hence for performance Closure Compiler would compile it to `variable||(variable={})`. BTW you're missing `NaN` in your falsy values list.

Comment: You forgot `NaN`. However, you should skip this list and reference to [`toBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2). See also http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11

Comment: Though "assigned to itself" is technically more accurate, I guess "don't do anything" is valid (in terms that it has no visible effect) and simpler to understand. Well, guess people can understand it either way. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté "assigned to itself" isn't always a no-op - there might be a `setter` on the variable if it's a global (and as such a property of the `window` object).

Comment: @Alnitak Makes sense, I forgot about setters completely. Also, a getter could also perform some other ops before returning the value.

Answer (score 1):

If variable is undefined or false, it initializes it to an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

It is to test if `variable` is initialized. If not, it initializes `variable` as an empty object. If it does exist, it does nothing, (technically assigns `variable` to itself).

Answer (score 1):

If variable already exists use it, otherwise create an empty object